# javax print vs java awt print api

Tags: java, printing, jakarta-ee, awt

Can i use java awt print to print a document/file instead of using javax print? I could find that in java awt print there is an option to set the content to be printed only as string using AttributedString. Is there an option to use awt and print document/file from input stream instead of String?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an implementation of Printable that reads a file and paints each page.  Then pass it to a PrinterJob.

Answer (score -2):

javax print is used to query about printer info and sending print jobs while java awt print api is used to print the actual document.excellent explanation [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_20956544.html).

Comment: Please answer the question in full rather than link to Experts Exchange with their paywall.